# Dynamically generated menu items -- figuring out which one was clicked

Tags: qt

I am parsing an XML document that holds a list of menu bar items. In other words, if I have 5 elements in the XML tree then I'll create 5 `QAction *` variables and add them to the `QMenu`. So the number of items is dynamic and not known at compile time.

The problem is figuring out how to do the callbacks. Since I do not know the number of `QAction *` variables I cannot simply create a callback for each one:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(item1Clicked()));
connect(anotherAction, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(item2Clicked()));
connect(yetAnotherAction, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(item3Clicked()));
....
```

I thought about creating one callback:

```
void menuItemClicked(int index)
```

But the problem is that I cannot connect the parameterless `clicked()` signal to the `menuItemClicked(int)` slot.

What other strategy is there?

### Update -- got this far

```
class MainWindow
{
private slots:
  void helpDocumentation(int);
  ...
```

Then

```
void MainWindow::helpDocumentation(int index)
{
  // do some logging
}
```

And

```
void MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
QDomElement rootElement = doc.documentElement();
  QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("document");
  QMenu * documentationMenu = helpMenu->addMenu("Documentation");
  QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); ++i)
  {
    QDomNode node = nodes.item(i);

    QDomElement element = node.toElement();
    if (!element.isNull())
    {
      // Item is an element.
      QString fileAttr = element.attribute("file");
      QString nameAttr = element.attribute("name");

      documentationItems.push_back(qMakePair(fileAttr, nameAttr));

      QAction * action = new QAction(nameAttr, helpMenu);
      connect(action, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
      signalMapper->setMapping(action, i);
      documentationMenu->addAction(action);
    }
  }

  connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(helpDocumentation(int)));
}
```

The items are added to the menu bar but the helpDocumentation(int) slot is not called.

Comment: `QAction` does not have a `clicked()` signal. Use `SIGNAL(triggered())` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tilman answer edited. I removed the code from the question for future readers

Comment: By the way, connecting a non existing signal should produce a warning in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the sender() function inside the slot, it will tell you which QAction triggered the signal.

```
QObject * s = sender();

if(s==action)
{
    //Do something here
}
else if(s==anotherAction)
{
    //Do something here
}
else if(s==yetAnotherAction)
{
    //Do something here
}
```

If you absolutely want an index parameter, look for QSignalMapper. It does exactly what you want : connecting several parameterless signals to a single slot taking a parameter as integer, associating a unique integer index for each connected signal.

You first create the signal mapper:

```
QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
```

You connect each signal to the signalMapper map() slot:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(anotherAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(yetAnotherAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
```

Then you tell the signal mapper which sender has which index:

```
signalMapper->setMapping(action, 0);
signalMapper->setMapping(anotherAction, 1);
signalMapper->setMapping(yetAnotherAction, 2);
```

Then you connect the outbound mapped(int) signal to your slot

```
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(menuItemClicked(int)));
```

By the way, the signalmapper is a very simple class which uses sender() and look up in a hash table associating QObject* senders to integer indices.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer -- I finally understand QSignalMapper now. I tried to implement your solution and unfortunately the slot did not get called. I edited my post to show the code. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: As Tilman noticed, QAction has no clicked() signal. Replaced by triggered().

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) as pointed out by galinette.

More specialized for actions: [`QActionGroup`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html). For that, you can attach meta-data to your actions using [`QAction::setData()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#setData) which you can access when handling the [`QActionGroup::triggered(QAction *)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html#triggered) signal.